# What is the correct way of normalizing/standardizing image-like data?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, computer-vision, normalization

I have image-like data (e.g. H x W x C), where each channel contains quite different information. You can think of it being a 2D map (H x W) with information like elevation, wind velocity, temperature as channels (C).

This data is fed into a neural network to make predictions. IMHO it is common sense that (for most cases) the input should follow a Gaussian with mean zero and unit variance. We see that in every MNIST example where we standardize `img = (img - mean) / std`.

The channels in my data follow quite different distributions, some of which carry exact meaning, e.g. wind velocity is given in [m/s]. Some of them are also correlated, e.g. velocities in x and y direction.

Just feeding in everything without any normalization/standardization does not yield any results I can be proud of, yet normalizing them in a naive way should not work well.

What is the best way to normalize these data?

The approaches on top of my head:

1. Standardize per channel. Might destroy some correlations due to slightly different distributions.
2. Standardize per "logical units", e.g. one operation for temperature, one for velocities in x and y (calculate mean,std over both channels). Some channels might not follow a zero mean and unit variance then.
3. Standardize over entire data. Sounds like the worst of all worlds, but what do I know.
4. Instead of input standardization, use LayerNorm in the first network layer(s?). Here we have at least two options again (see 1./2.).

Comment: I would go for 2, as it would preserve as much information as possible. It just seems to make sense to me. But CNNs often break logic, we don't understand them well enough to be able to predict what will work best. So we try all possible options and see what works best. Building a CNN is not science, it's trial and error.

Comment: for some of your analog values, if they require some amount of precision, you might want to consider "encodings". sin/cos encodings are popular. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_coding

Comment: The objection to (1) isn't true. The correlation between two variables is not changed by subtracting the mean, dividing by the standard deviation, or both. You can generate data with a specified correlation and then check if the correlation is the same before the proposed transformation as it is after.

Comment: yes, there's really no harm in standardizing like that, and it can be super helpful. Neural network initilizers, optimizers, even the inductive bias of common neural net designs are designed to work with input data in that range (or [0,1] should be fine too, i.e.subtract min then divide by max-min), and standardizing axis-by-axis leaves the correlation structure identical. This is especially true if you have any regularization, cause if you don't standardize, you're applying unequal regularization to different input weights.

Comment: regarding the "exact meaning of m/s", the neural net does not appreciate SI units as much as you do :) much more important to have input data with magnitudes anticipated by the designers of neural net libraries.